# Confusion about how to use condition type 1 and 2

Tags: conditionals

Ok, the condition type 1 predicts a possible future event:

*If this thing happens, that thing will happen.*

The condition type 1 expresses a counterfactual situation with a present or future time frame:

*If this thing happened, that thing would happen (but I'm not sure this thing will happen) OR that thing would be happening.*

Ok, now if you say:

> If I marry Mary, I will be happy

> If I married Mary, I would be happy

In the first sentence, you are quite confident that if you marry Mary then you will have a happy life. Maybe you think that Mary is a very good girl, etc. But in the 2nd question, you are not sure that will happen, right?

I am a bit confused, because it seems that you choose to say the 1st or 2nd question based on what you think in your head. If you think you could marry Mary in the future, then use the 1st one, and if you think you could not marry Mary in the future, then use the 2nd one: is that right?

So, is it all depending on your thinking? If you think it is possible then use the condition type 1 & if you think it is impossible then use the condition type 2?

Ok, see other examples:

> If I have a spacecraft, I will fly to the moon

> If I had a spacecraft, I would fly to the moon

Ok, I think it is up to you to say the 1st or 2nd sentence. If you say the 1st one, then you think it could happen.

For example, maybe a few years later you have enough money to make a spacecraft and fly to the moon. But if you think that there is no way you can make enough money to buy a spacecraft to fly to the moon, then you can use the 2nd option right?

So does choosing type 1 or 2 depend on what we think? Or are we forced to use only 1 structure, meaning that type 1 or 2 is not governed by what we think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry...I'm a little confused about your question...
In both situations, you believe that the outcome will occur if the conditions are met. In either case you are confident in the outcome.

If I marry Mary, I will be happy. If I married Mary, I would be happy. (In both cases, I strongly believe I will/would be happy).

The difference is condition 2 is less possible than condition 1. If I think its possible that I will marry Mary or have a spacecraft in the future, I should use condition 1.
If I marry Mary, I will be happy.
If I have a spacecraft, I will fly to the moon.

If I don't think the situation is possible, I should use condition 2.
If I married Mary, I would be happy.
If I had a spacecraft, I would fly to the moon.

Comment: So, we use the condition 1 ("If I have a spacecraft, I will fly to the moon") or 2 ("If I had a spacecraft, I would fly to the moon") by based on what we think, right?

Comment: @Tom: Yes, based on what you think is probable.